# delete function property from JavaScript generic object

Tags: javascript, web, knockout.js

I have a JavaScript object with some properties, one of the properties is function, I want to delete the function property. 
the problem is that the the JavaScript model is generic, I don't know the property name.
How can I do it?

Comment: you can check by using for in loop in object and then using delete delete it

Comment: We need more context, show us an example of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you think you need to do this, usually you need to go further into the problem to find the root cause (why the object has this function you feel you need to delete in the first place).

You can remove *all* properties from an object that refer to a function like this, assuming they're *own*, *enumerable* properties:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(theObject)) {
    if (typeof theObject[key] === "function") {
        delete theObject[key];
    }
}
```

If it may not be enumerable, we can use `getOwnPropertyNames` instead:

```
for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(theObject)) {
    if (typeof theObject[key] === "function") {
        delete theObject[key];
    }
}
```

Add a `break;` if you want to stop with the first one.

Both of those examples are ES2015+; if you need to do it in ES5, use `forEach` (or `some` if you want to stop early):

```
Object.keys(theObject).some(function(key) {
    if (typeof theObject[key] === "function") {
        delete theObject[key];
        return true; // If you want to stop on the first; if not,
                     // remove this and use `forEach` instead
    }
});
```

---

But again, this sounds like an X/Y problem, where you want to do X, and think Y is how to do it, and asked about Y. I suspect if you look deeper you'll want to solve X instead.